# tinyMCE error in IE but not in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm writing a htm+javascript page where i want to use the tinyMCE text editor.
When i load the page i receive the error:

```
Agente utente: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)  
Timestamp: Sun, 13 Jan 2013 16:44:35 UTC  
Message: 'tinyMCE.get(...)' is null or is not an object
```

I see the error only on IE, no error when i use Chrome or FireFox (??).
The code line is:

```
if(msgNatale!=undefined) tinyMCE.get("edit1").setContent(msgNatale);
```

The object 'edit1' is a textarea:

```
<textarea name="edit1" id="edit1" rows=15 cols=70></textarea>
```

Any idea??

Comment: tinyMCE.get("edit1") will yield a result if the editor is already initialized - is this the case in IE?

Comment: The code is into a js function fn() called on <body ... onLoad="fn();">

Comment: it is best practive to use document.ready

Comment: My guess is that is a jQuery function, but mine is not jQuery code